# How can I reproduce the key (multiple) in Caching Spring Boot to evict? And spring-context-support issue?

Tags: java, spring-boot, caching

I using cache by multiple keys like this

```java
    @Cacheable(
         value = "cache_name",
         key = "{#id, #name}"
    )
```

I'd like to evict it in another function using CacheManager

```java
    Long id = 123L;
    String name = "abc";


    cacheManager.getCache("cache_name").evict(cacheKey);
```

**Question #1:** How can I create `cacheKey` to match with real key created by @Cacheable

The real key when I print is a String like this: `[123, abc]`

I tried with SimpleKey, but it does not work

And I tried with:

```java
String cacheKey = Arrays.toString(new String[]{id.toString(), name});
```

Ofcourse, it does not work also.

**Question #2:**

Currently, I'm using solution to call void function and use `@CacheEvict` in separate Service (ex: CacheService)

It's ok when I call directly this function, but when I call it via another function (same function in the CacheService, the cache doesn't evict? Why? Look like I lose context of spring? Any advice?

Thank you.

Comment: You have to use spring proxy for `@CacheEvict` annotation to work. If you call the function from another function in same service, the proxy won't be invoked. That is why it is not working.

Comment: @Kekar Thank you, I move the function to another service, and it's work fine. Thank you so much.

As your key word, I found this article mention about this issue **Invocation of cacheable methods from the same class**
https://medium.com/upday-devs/3-common-mistakes-when-implementing-spring-cache-abstraction-a7ac2ee247ba